# Cannot upgrade Rails from 4.0.0 to 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to upgrade ruby on rails on my Mac, but somehow `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` always pops up.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150422-3384-60m3u9.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.

To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Are you reading the instructions? Doesn't look like it. Someone took time to write this explanation that tells you exactly how to fix it,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing xcode like the error message says

`xcode-select --install`